# How to remotely delete subfolders older than x days using forfiles

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

I need to remotely delete sub folders older than 7 days, was able to find a syntax like this, but what it does is it loops through the subfolders and deletes the files in it older than 7 days. Any idea how can I delete the subfolders in xFOLDER older than 7 days as well?

```
PushD "\\IP ADDRESS\FOLDERA\FOLDERB\FOLDERC\FOLDERD\xFOLDER\" & ("forfiles.exe" /s /m "." /d -7 /c "cmd /c del @file") & PopD
```

Comment: change the mask from `*.*` to `*` and use the `rmdir` command; inside of the `forfiles` loop you can check whether an item is a file or a dir. by variable `@isdir`...

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, just a few things need to be changed:

- no `/S` for `forfiles`, as you are interested in the immediate subdirectories of `xFOLDER` only;
- the search mask needs to be changed from `.` to `*`;
- to skip all enumerated files, a check is required (using `if`); `forfiles` delivers a variable `@isdir` which indicates whether the current item is a file (`FALSE`) or a directory (`TRUE`);
- `del` deletes files, so to delete directories, `rmdir` is required; switch `/S` allows to delete even non-empty directories, switch `/Q` prevents any prompts whether or not to delete;

So this modified code should do what you want (written as multiple lines for legibility reasons):

```
PushD "\\IP ADDRESS\FOLDERA\FOLDERB\FOLDERC\FOLDERD\xFOLDER\" ^
  & ("forfiles.exe" /P "*" /D -7 /C "cmd /C if @isdir==TRUE rmdir /S /Q @path") ^
  & PopD
```